# Перегрузка оператора присваивания c#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, на паре форумов прочитал, что перегрузить этот оператор невозможно. Как решить эту проблему? '

```
{
    public static void operator = (Person p, Person p1);
}`
```

Просто если использовать ArrayList.Colone(), то изменяя новую коллекцию я изменяю и исходную, как это возможно избежать? Спасибо за внимание, подскажите куда копать.

Comment: А в чём ваша проблема? Да, перегрузить присваивание невозможно, так что скорее всего ваша проблема решается по-другому.

Comment: Моя проблема  в копировании эллементов  одной коллекции в другую

Comment: в таком случае унаследуйте ваш класс `Person` от интерфейса `IClonable` и реализуйте метод `Clone` по своему. Он как раз для этого предназначен

Comment: Person это элемент массива, а не коллекция так что   public object Clone()
    {
        return new Person(this);
    } не помогло

Comment: Person это тип элемента массива, и судя по тому, что при копировании у вас возникают проблемы - это тип ссылочный т.е. класс. Другой вопрос, если у вас нет доступа к его исходникам.

Comment: да  исходники есть, но переопределение метода Clone  у класса Person  не принесло результата. Наверное надо делать свою коллекцию  и переопределять  в ней метод Clone. Но это лобовое и геморройное решение, неужели у шарпа нету альтернативы?

Comment: вы просто не с той стороны смотрите. Подождите пару минут.

Comment: А зачем вам клонировать `Person`? Что вам это даст?

Comment: Ну и понятно, чтобы `new Person(this)` откомпилировалось, у `Person` должен быть конструктор `Person(Person other)`.

Comment: задача в лабораторной так поставлена "используя ArrayList персонов реализовать метод DeepCopy который в свою очередь будет  создавать новый объект класса в котором содержится ArrayList персонов и эти ArrayList должны быть независимы"

Comment: так конструктор есть  public Person(Person p)
    {
        Fname = p.Fname;
        Sname = p.Sname;
        Btime = p.Btime;
    }

Comment: ну так и делайте отдельный метод. причем тут `ArayList.Clone`?

Comment: а как копировать отдельные элементы я написал ниже

Comment: Ну я думал есть стандартный метод поэлементного копирования независимыми  элементами. Я просто с базой С++, и меня часто ругают, что я велосипеды горожу когда есть готовые решение.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, за потраченное время. И что вы несмотря на мою непробиваемость докопались до сути вопроса и решили его.

Comment: это стандартное решение. Можно конечно и совсем ленивый вариант - сделать Person структурой и ArrayList.Clone, но я бы за такое побил...

Comment: и еще, вместо ArrayList используйте лучше List<T> если задание позволяет

Comment: На самом деле есть оператор неявного преобразования [implicit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) но в него нужно передавать только один параметр

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор присваивания, как и некоторые другие действительно нельзя переопределить (см. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8edha89s.aspx)). Но если у вас есть доступ к исходникам класса `Person`, то для решения вашей задачи достаточно унаследовать класс `Person` от интерфейса `IClonable` и реализовать этот интерфейс примерно так:

```
public class Person : IClonable
{
    // тут ваши поля и методы

    public object Clone()
    {
         var personClone = new Person();
         //тут копируем в новую сущность нужные свойства
         return personClone;
    }
}
```

После этого вы совершенно спокойно можете копировать элементы, например так:

```
Person p1 = new Person()
{
    //присвоили значения полям
}

Person p2 = p1.Clone();
```

В этом случае, `p2` получит новую ссылку на свой собственный объект `Person`. Правда копировать коллекцию придется вручную поэлементно в цикле, т.к. реализованный у стандартных коллекций метод `Clone` делает неполное копирование и в случае элементов ссылочного типа - копирует ссылки. Но на этот случай можно предусмотреть статический метод в классе `Person` получающий на вход коллекцию и возвращающий ее копию.